# adding users to different groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table entitled users. It has a UID, rating, username, password, etcetera.

My goal is to make a system (tribes) similar to Facebook's friends list. Each user will be able to view the profile of users and add them to their tribe. Each user is the chief of only one tribe, but can be the villager of as many tribes as he/she wants to be. The rating system would take into account all of the tribe's members ratings.

After doing some research on relational database tables and grouping, I am not clear about how I should go about setting up the tables, or the PHP code that would go along with that.

If someone can get me pointed in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated!

EDIT: One of the big problems I foresee is accepting to be in a tribe. I'm not sure how you account for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> similar to Facebook's friends list. Each user will be able to view the profile of users and add them to their tribe. Each user is the chief of only one tribe

Okay, so you have a `User` table, and also will need a `Tribe` table.

Then the relations you're describing are a `chief-of`, which is one-to-one (one user can be chief of one tribe; one tribe has only one chief), therefore you can either store this within `User` (chief_of: Tribe) or within `Tribe` (chief: User).

```
CREATE TABLE User ...
    chief_of integer
```

Here, `chief_of` might be a foreign key so that if you delete a tribe, the relevant tuple will have its `chief_of` set to NULL (a user can't be chief of a no longer existing tribe).

The membership is a bit more complicated because one user can belong to several tribes, and a tribe will have more than one member.

This is a many-to-many relationship and is usually done with a table holding key pairs:

```
CREATE TABLE member_of (
    user_id integer,
    tribe_id integer
);
```

Both fields are natural candidates for foreign keys. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/Implementamanytomanymap.htm) you can find a similar implementation using `Authors` and `Books`.

To indicate that Bob is a member of the Clan of the Cave Bear, you retrieve the ids of Bob and Bears, and insert a tuple in `member_of`.

To retrieve all members of the clan, you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT Users.* FROM Users
    JOIN member_of ON (Users.user_id = member_of.user_id)
    WHERE member_of.tribe_id =
        (SELECT tribe_id FROM Tribes WHERE tribe_name = 'Clan of the Cave Bear');
```

I think that a shorter version of that ON in MySQL is `USING(user_id)` (meaning that both tables have an identical column identically named), but in my opinion the `ON` is clearer.

You can also retrieve a virtual "is_chief" column:

```
SELECT Users.*, chief_of = tribe_id AS is_chief FROM Users
    JOIN member_of ON (Users.user_id = member_of.user_id)
    WHERE member_of.tribe_id =
        (SELECT tribe_id FROM Tribes WHERE tribe_name = 'Clan of the Cave Bear');
```

The one user whose `chief_of` attribute is equal to the tribe id will have `is_chief` set to TRUE, which is equal to 1, so

```
SELECT Users.*, chief_of = tribe_id AS is_chief FROM Users
    JOIN member_of ON (Users.user_id = member_of.user_id)
    WHERE member_of.tribe_id =
        (SELECT tribe_id FROM Tribes WHERE tribe_name = 'Clan of the Cave Bear')
    ORDER BY (chief_of = tribe_id) DESC, user_name;
```

will retrieve the users in alphabetical order, except the chief, who, if present, will come first.

As for the acceptance into the tribe, this identifies three *states*: a user is not in a tribe, a user is in the tribe, a user *asked to be* in a tribe. The first two are actually two faces of the same attribute `member_of`. So naturally we might create a new attribute and call it `wants_in`. It would map to a table identical to `member_of`.

A chief could retrieve all tuples of `wants_in` whose `tribe_id` is equal to his own `chief_of` (so if it's NULL, meaning he's *not* a chief, this will automatically return *nothing*). Then he might see this as a table of checkboxes with user names. When he approves the join, for each approval you delete the tuple from `wants_in` and put it into `member_of`.

Or you might decide that "membership" is a state in itself, so that you have a more complex join table

```
user_id,
tribe_id,
status
```

where `status` could be, say,

- nothing (there's no (U, T, ?) tuple): user U and tribe T are unknown to each other
- 100: user U is full member of tribe T
- -1 : tribe T has decided that U is not a member *and cannot even ask to be*.
- 0: user U wants to be member of T
- 1-99: user U is a probationary (apprentice) member.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I'll try and wrap my head around this.

Comment: You did not say whether you're using a framework, an ORM, and which one. If you do, all the above is probably already supplied and you only need to "inform" the framework that, e.g., `User` has a many-to-many "member" relationship, and a one-to-one "chief" relationship, with `Tribe`. The ORM will do the rest. You might be interested in checking out, e.g., Laravel.

Comment: +1 Holy crap.  I came back here like "WTF lost the accept?" but this is fantastic.  One of those answers I wish I could +1 multiple times.

Comment: Well, I feel that - except for my comment - I understated a **very important** point that you made, that can spell the difference between a successful project and an unmaintenable mess: encapsulating models and classes rather than going all the way with SQL. Hence my upvote for *you* :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll need two classes: `Villager` and `Tribe`.

Then, maybe a database field called `chief_of` or something that is `null` if the person is not a chief, and contains the name of their tribe that they are the chief.

In the classes you can have a `getChiefOf()` method that can be tested to see if the user is a chief or not.

---

Alternatively, you could have a table of chiefs, indexed by UID, with the same column that says which tribe they're chief of.  A little less efficient but a better structure.  A drawback that jumps to mind is if the UID for some reason is changed, two tables would have to be updated, so maybe the first one's better.

Comment: sorry I'm not well versed in programming speak. When you say classes, does that refer to creating a table for Villager and Tribe, or something else?

Comment: Mmmm, no...classes are a collection of functions that you'll need every time you work with a `Villager` or `Tribe`.  Simple stuff, like `getName()` or `getWife()` or `howManyGoats()` or something.  Then, on each page, you make an instance of that class (`$Client = new Villager()`) and you automatically have that set of functions at your disposal.  In those functions, you can add something like `getTribe()` and `getTribeChief()` that give you more info about those details.  Spend a few days learning about classes and your programming skills will be awesomeified dramatically.

Comment: BTW `$Client` is the user.  When you do the logic for each page you can get the user info from the database and use it with your other classes, rather than rewriting everything on every page.

Comment: After re-reading your comment, yes, you'll probably need a table of tribes, and a table of villagers.  Your classes are go-betweens which pull data from these tables.

Comment: I appreciate all the input. I'll give you an uptick and a check mark, but I obviously need to do a lot of figuring. I'm drawing it out on paper.

Comment: Cheers, yeah, I'd start with PHP classes because they're a) pretty darn helpful and b) that's how most programming languages work.